# (SQL Server) SQL doesn't allow creating a procedure after checking if it exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Below is the sql I am trying to use to check if the store procedure doesnot exists then create the procedure.
it throws an error: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.procedures WHERE name = N'[Reports].[usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel]')
BEGIN

CREATE PROCEDURE [Reports].[usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel]   @OrganisationID INT, @Category2 varchar(30) = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
     --SOME SQL..
  END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is not included in the `name`; the `name` is just `usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel`, and you can check the schema via

```
schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('Reports')
```

Aside: note that it is actually `sys.procedures`, not `SYS.procedures` - this is important if the server is configured to be case-sensitive.

`ALTER PROC` / `CREATE PROC` must be the first statement in a batch, so you need to be a little creative in how you do this. In the general case of wanting a re-runnable create-or-update script, the following approach works:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[Reports].[usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [Reports].[usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel] AS BEGIN PRINT ''impl'' END');
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [Reports].[usp_EMS_Stats_DashboardPendingBookingSel]   @OrganisationID INT, @Category2 varchar(30) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
     PRINT 'HI'; -- your actual code here
END
```

Comment: Agree, Schema is not included in the name, However using this Approach I loose all the IntelliSense  and end up writing the procedure as string..

Comment: @hussian no you don't! the actual procedure code goes in the **second** block, not the first; intellisense works just fine - see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LhQxX.png ; the code in the `EXEC` code is just placeholder and doesn't ever need to do anything or be edited, as long as it is valid TSQL.

Comment: still, this kills the purpose, I don't want to update or create the procedure if it already exists in the database. if i had to do so i could just do drop and create procedure.

Comment: @hussian syntax for that does not exist, unless you use `exec` and code it as a string; however, "drop and create" is a major no-no on a live system (it can break running apps), where-as the alter-proc approach above will lead to the correct schema locks etc being observed, so no outage

Comment: well that's a big news for me that "Drop and Create is a major no no"..
we are so much relying on this.. can you please elaborate how else would we take our procedure changes to live envirnoments..
Considering we store our scripts in a folder and when we run live deployments we just execute these procedures..

Comment: I really Appreciate the knowledge you have and your time though.

Comment: @hussian "can you please elaborate how else would we take our procedure changes to live envirnoments" - by exactly what I've shown above! the important point is that if this is an existing in-use procedure on a live system, there is never a moment where the procedure doesn't exist, so you won't get a pile of 2812 ("Could not find stored procedure") errors in the millisecond between the drop batch and the create batch.